Could the scattering of molecules lead to bond compression?
Suppose you were to send a fast moving binary molecule (such as H-H) at another large target atom A such that the molecule is aligned with the direction of its travel towards the target atom. In other words H,H, and A are all colinear. However, let’s say the atom A is moving in the exact opposite direction and will collide with the H-H molecule. Additionally, atom A has more momentum and energy than the incoming H-H molecule.  Next let’s say that some type of inelastic scattering occurs in which the molecule H-H ends up scattering back in the exact reverse direction.  Since the leading atom of the H-H molecule must have felt the force from atom A before the lagging side of the binary molecule is there any chance this could lead to the first H in the molecule slowing (for a brief point in time) before the second bonded H which is farther from the target nucleus. Could this lead to a brief moment of bond compression due to the scattering and the momentum of the atom A?

The vibrational modes of the hydrogen molecule would absolutely be affected by this and it would cause the structure of the molecule (and the way that it oscillates) to change throughout the scattering process. But since this is so vague that is all that can be said.

Why such a complicated setup? Just do molecular spectroscopy at high pressure.

With sufficiently high speeds involved could this lead to a fusion of the hydrogen atoms upon scattering?
